# NodeJS create a storybook like youtube videos?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I need to be creating something like this:

[image]

This image was generated using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-generate-video-preview

However its not really suitable because my storybook has to be limited to 10x10 rows/cols and after every image I have to create a next one of 10x10. And I can't really make it generate rows/columns automatically because it just doesn't know what is the maximum amount of cols to generate based on the frames.

How can I do such thing with maybe using ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems like you need two steps:
1. use ffmpeg to generate the keyframes
2. arrange those keyframes visually into a 10x10 grid.

FFmpeg can do the first, but not the second.  The package you linked to is doing both of these things in a specific way.

Take the package you linked to and consider forking it, and add some logic to change the output to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using FFMPEG for creating the keyframes and then by using [Montage](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) to create the grid.